# How do I use basic auth with RestKit's getObject?

Tags: ios, restkit

I tried the following to set the basic auth username and password, but it does not seem to be passing the basic auth in the request..

```
secureManager = [[RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://localhost:3000"] retain];

secureManager.client.username = uname;
secureManager.client.password = pwd;


RKObjectLoader *loader = [svc getObject:user delegate:self];

loader.userData = [NSNumber numberWithInt:RequestLogin];
```

UPDATE: found my problem, I needed to add the following snippet

```
secureManager.client.forceBasicAuthentication = YES;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can grab an instance of the underlying RKClient before you make your request and set the Username and Password like so:

```
// Set the Username and Password
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.username = @"username"; 
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.password = @"letmein";

// Make our Request
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObject:user mapResponseWith:mapping delegate:self];
```

As MonkeyBonkey points out in the comments, you may need to force the authentication using a flag:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.forceBasicAuthentication = YES;
```

Comment: fixed by adding vc.client.forceBasicAuthentication = YES;

Comment: Excellent, i'll add that in my answer and credit it to you for any future users

Comment: What is user in this situation?