# How to specify Restkit object manager to perform a POST

Tags: objective-c, ios, restkit

I am trying to send a POST request using ios Restkit. I can perform a GET, but cannot find how to send a POST.

My current code looks like the following:

```
RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:@"/users/sign_in.json" queryParameters:params];

[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [URL resourcePath], [URL query]]  delegate:self];
```

Apparently, this performs a GET. Any idea what I should add to make it a POST?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't look very RESTful.  Given what it looks like you're doing, why not use one of the authentication methods built in to HTTP instead of turning REST in to RPC?

Comment: I would, but the server does not seem to accept HTTP authentication request. It returns a 500 error. Instead, sending an email and password via a json post seems to work.

Comment: I have no idea what your server looks like, but generally you'll probably need to do some server coding/configuration to accept the authentication.  If you're using Java/Spring then it's easy via Spring-Security.

Comment: I am using rails and the devise plugin for authentication. I used a browser rest client, I'll give it some research to see how I can get it to accept HTTP authentication. Is there some advantage of using HTTP authentication than sending username & password via a POST? If so, what could I do to the code above to send HTTP Authentication request - is RESTKit capable of doing that? Thanks! :)

Comment: I've done very little Rails, but it's all about doing REST right, right? :)   Anyway, here's how to make RestKit do basic auth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455269/how-do-i-use-basic-auth-with-restkits-getobject . The disadvantage of doing JSON POST is that it implies state (session) and the idea, I believe, that the server is stateless, so just pass the auth each time (over SSL in production of course).

Comment: Ah thanks Brindy! That makes sense. Your comment/answer cleared out quite a few doubts I had. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question (regardless of the above discussion) you can do the following:

```
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath: @"path" usingBlock: ^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.HTTPMethod = RKRequestMethodPOST;
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your RKRequest with:

```
[request setMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```